# Payment integration with next.js

Tags: api, frontend, payment, paypal, integration

I am using Magento in the backend with Nextjs in the front, I need to integrate payment using the Magento extension but don't know how Magneto will communicate with Nextjs. Can someone provide me with some info about this process, do I need to create a costume endpoint in Magento?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.